# .net 4.5 mouse event of wpf WindowsFormsHost hosting a windows form control

Tags: wpf, windowsformshost

I host a windows form control in wpf WindowsFormsHost in .net4.5 wpf, like

```
<Grid MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown" Background="#FFE85050">

    <WindowsFormsHost HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="244"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="335" 
                      MouseDown="WindowsFormsHost_MouseDown">
        <ctrl:UserControl1 x:Name="aa" MouseClick="aa_MouseClick"/>
    </WindowsFormsHost>

</Grid>
```

the aa_MouseClick fires correctly but WindowsFormsHost_MouseDown and Grid_MouseDown never fires(the windows form control eat the event), how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Event handling startegy of `WPF` and `WinForms` is completely different. `MouseDown` event handled in Winforms can't be propagated up to WPF control. `WPF uses routed event instead of old event handling of WinForms.`

Even event handlers differ in signature. What you can do is hook `MouseDown` event on `WinForms control` and can `do your stuff from there`.

OR

You can try approach mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475518/bubble-mouse-event-from-wpf-to-winforms), its other way round though from WPF to Winforms but can be applied in your situation as well.

Comment: it's different, I know, but is there any method can pass event message(window message) directly to wpf but not to winforms inside WindowsFormsHost?

Comment: No there's no such method. As i mentioned in another approach, you need to create your custom event in WinForms and hook to that event in WPF. Raise that event from WinForms handler and listen in WPF.

Comment: Thanks, there is a HwndHost, basically I can use it to achieve the same purpose, and if override the WndProc to not handle window message, wpf can recieve event

Comment: Yeah that will work too. Do post your answer once you achieved. Would love to have a look at it.. :)

Answer (score 0):

My purpose is create a window hwnd to render something, but not care about the event
here is the solution that I am now using

```
public class RenderHwndHost : HwndHost
{
    public delegate void AfterSizeChangedHandler();

    internal const int
        WS_CHILD = 0x40000000,
        WS_VISIBLE = 0x10000000,
        LBS_NOTIFY = 0x00000001,
        HOST_ID = 0x00000002,
        LISTBOX_ID = 0x00000001,
        WS_VSCROLL = 0x00200000,
        WS_BORDER = 0x00800000;

    private IntPtr hwndHost;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "DestroyWindow", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal static extern bool DestroyWindow(IntPtr hwnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateWindowEx", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal static extern IntPtr CreateWindowEx(int dwExStyle,
        string lpszClassName,
        string lpszWindowName,
        int style,
        int x, int y,
        int width, int height,
        IntPtr hwndParent,
        IntPtr hMenu,
        IntPtr hInst,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AsAny)] object pvParam);

    protected override IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        handled = false;
        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    protected override void DestroyWindowCore(HandleRef hwnd)
    {
        DestroyWindow(hwnd.Handle);
    }

    protected override void OnRenderSizeChanged(SizeChangedInfo sizeInfo)
    {
        base.OnRenderSizeChanged(sizeInfo);
        if (AfterSizeChanged != null)
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                new Action(() => AfterSizeChanged()));
        }
    }

    public event AfterSizeChangedHandler AfterSizeChanged;

    protected override HandleRef BuildWindowCore(HandleRef hwndParent)
    {
        hwndHost = CreateWindowEx(0, "static", "",
            WS_CHILD,
            0, 0,
            100, 100,
            hwndParent.Handle,
            (IntPtr) HOST_ID,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            0);


        return new HandleRef(this, hwndHost);
    }
```